# Cursor, не удается получить список отправленных смс

Tags: android, sms, cursor

Здравствуйте, не удается получить курсором список отправленных смс вместе с их статусами. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

```
case R.id.button2:                    
                Uri sms_sent = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
                ContentResolver content = getContentResolver();
                Cursor crs = content.query(sms_sent, null/* new String[]{"_id","address", "status"}*/, null, null, null);

                crs.moveToFirst();
                int id = crs.getColumnIndex("_id");
                int number = crs.getColumnIndex("address");
                int readStatus = crs.getColumnIndex("status");

                if (number < 0 || !crs.moveToFirst()) return;

                do {
                    String string_phone_status = "Отправлено: " + crs.getString(id) + " " + crs.getString(number) + "_статус: "
                            +crs.getString(readStatus);
                    editMultiline_for_sms.setText(string_phone_status);
                }while (crs.moveToNext());

                crs.close();
```

метод moveToFirst() выдает такое предупреждение:

```
Method invocation 'moveToFirst' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointException'
```

На реальном девайсе (LG E455) выдает след. лог:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4101)
                                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17088)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5071)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
                                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4101) 
                                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17088) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5071) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557) 
                                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                         Caused by: android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed.
                                                                                            at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.throwIfCursorIsClosed(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:64)
                                                                                            at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.getColumnNames(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:159)
                                                                                            at android.database.CursorWrapper.getColumnNames(CursorWrapper.java:86)
                                                                                            at com.example.turbolocb.smsconnector.MainActivity.onClickButton(MainActivity.java:235)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4101) 
                                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17088) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5071) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557) 
                                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

В эмуляторе лог почему-то другой:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: com.example.turbolocb.smsconnector, PID: 6099
                                                                                      java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.telephony.SmsProvider uri content://sms/sent from pid=6099, uid=10061 requires android.permission.READ_SMS, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
                                                                                          at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
                                                                                          at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
                                                                                          at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
                                                                                          at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:491)
                                                                                          at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:434)
                                                                                          at com.example.turbolocb.smsconnector.MainActivity.onClickButton(MainActivity.java:203)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Содержимое манифеста:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.turbolocb.smsconnector">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Судя по логам эмулятора, у вас нет пермишена на чтение SMS - покажите свой манифест

Comment: @Barmaley да с пермишенами все в порядке, вроде. Проблему, кстати, решил отчасти, но на эмуляторе по-прежнему не работает, манифест добавил к вопросу.

Comment: Ааа, ну понятно, на эмуляторе не работает потому что версия API такая, что требует рантайм пермишен